# Finding key-value pairs from log line, may be quoted, may contain quotes

Tags: php, regex, key-value

Looking for a regex to capture all quoted key-value pairs from a log line (exim, to be precise). However, the value can also contain quotes

Tried multiple examples from other SO questions (eg [Regular expression to match key-value pairs where value is in quotes or apostrophes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007616)), all have failed as soon as they hit an internal quote character

Test data, all valid examples:

```
A="value" F="something here" T="This is the value"
F="something \"here\"" T="The value's here" X=ignore
F="something's here" T="He said \"This is also the value\""
```

Comment: You can have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks) to see if it helps. You might need to combine it with the one from the other example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to match all individual key-value pairs:

```
(?<key>[^\s=]+)=(?<value>"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^\s"]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F80iJA/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<key>[^\s=]+)`: Match 1 or more characters that are not `=` and whitespaces, capture in group `"key"`
- `=`: Match a literal `=`
- `(?<value>`: Start capture group `"value"`

  - `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`: Match a quoted string ignoring all escaped character inside the `"..."`
  - `|`: OR
  - `[^\s"]+`: Match 1 or more characters that are not `=` and whitespaces
- `)`: End capture group `"value"`

Comment: Unfortunately `grep` doesn't give any option of retrieving capture groups.

Comment: oh ok, sorry sir to bug you here, could you please do lemme know whichever language its supported, like php, javascript etc sir?

Comment: Yes pretty much all languages support named groups like Java, python, Perl, C#, Javascript etcc.